# The 2010 Loebner Prize winner bot: Suzette

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp, chatbot

What are some of the techniques that a machine could use to be able to carry a good conversation/pass the Turing Test? I know this has to do with Natural Language Understanding and Processing, but I need more details.

I'm particularly interested in the chatbot Suzette who won the 2010 Loebner Prize.

Thank you

Comment: Quit trying to build SkyNet pls :(

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this nothing can yet pass the Turing Test.

Not an answer as such but if you're looking for something that can, then there isn't one yet known to man.